# Unable to set value of input tag from dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to set an input value from a dropdown list but it doesn't seem to work for me. this is my code:

```
<form>
    <select name="color" id="color">
        <option selected value="0">white</option>  
        <option value="1">orange</option> 
        <option value="1">black</option> 
        <option value="2">yellow</option>
        <option value="2">green</option>    
        <option value="4">gray</option> 
        <option value="4">red</option> 
        <option value="8">pink</option> 
        <option value="8">blue</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="output">
</form>
```

```js
$('#color').bind('change', function() {
    $('#output').html($(this).find(':selected').html() + '<br>');
    console.log($(this).find(':selected').html());
});
```

It works when I replace `<input type="text" id="output">` with `<div id="output"></div>`. Any solutions?

Comment: waht version of jquery are you using?use `.on()`

Comment: also `$('#output').val()` not `.hml()` as it's an input ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#output` element is an `input`, so you need to use `val()`, not `html()`, to set its value.

Also note that `bind()` is deprecated. You should use `change()` or `on('change')` instead. Try this:

```js
$('#color').on('change', function() {
  $('#output').val($(this).find(':selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select name="color" id="color">
    <option selected value="0">white</option>  
    <option value="1">orange</option> 
    <option value="1">black</option> 
    <option value="2">yellow</option>
    <option value="2">green</option>    
    <option value="4">gray</option> 
    <option value="4">red</option> 
    <option value="8">pink</option> 
    <option value="8">blue</option> 
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="output">
</form>
```

Comment: must delete + '<br>' from script because it's posted with value so it must be     <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#color').bind('change', function(){
   $('#output').val($(this).find(':selected').text());
   console.log($(this).find(':selected').html());
  });
 </script>

Answer (score 3):

Try this example,

```js
$('#color').bind('change', function() {
    $('#output').val($('#color option:selected').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <select name="color" id="color">
        <option selected value="0">white</option>  
        <option value="1">orange</option> 
        <option value="1">black</option> 
        <option value="2">yellow</option>
        <option value="2">green</option>    
        <option value="4">gray</option> 
        <option value="4">red</option> 
        <option value="8">pink</option> 
        <option value="8">blue</option> 
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="output">
</form>
```

I have made changes in your selection of option text.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#color').on('change', function() {
    //alert( this.value );
     $('#output').val(this.value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#color').bind('change', function(){
    $('#output').val($(this).find(':selected').html() + '<br>');
    console.log($(this).find(':selected').html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Input tags always has value so you have to change code to below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('change','#color', function(){

    $('#output').val($(this).find(':selected').html() + '<br>');

});

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

with input element it should be `val()` not `html()`

```
$(document).on('change','#color', function() {
    $('#output').val($(this).find(':selected').html());
});
```